# How to disable highlighting in XCode's Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

Is there a way to disable object highlighting in interface builder? I am testing out a lot of different colors for an object, but the highlighting is making it a difficult process.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use the "Simulate Interface" option under the File menu. The representations of the UI Elements in the editor are never exact. They're more concerned with position, hierarchy, outlets, bindings etc than visual nuances.